# Writing from Datahandler to file

Tags: java, web-services, file, mtom, datahandler

I created a web service using CXF/MTOM for transfering large files (over 700Mo), i managed to transfer the file to the server , now my question is to optimze writing data in disk, i will give examples :

```
DataHandler handler = fichier.getFichier();

InputStream is = handler.getInputStream();

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile"));


byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
os.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
     }
```

Using bytes can lead me to an OutOfMemory, so i'd rather use this one :

```
DataHandler handler = fichier.getFichier();

handler.writeTo(os);
```

this take 2 minutes for uploading 700Mo.

what are other efficient ways ?

thanks

Comment: 700MB in 2 minutes gives about 50mbps. Are you sure it's not the bandwitch that is slowing you down?

Comment: correct , copying the file locally within 1 minute

Comment: It can only lead to `OutOfMemoryError` if you use a ridiculously large buffer. So don't do that. And as you admit that the bandwidth is the rate-determining step, no code solution is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the class **IOUtils** of **Apache Commons IO**
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/package-summary.html

QN: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

```
DataHandler handler = docClient.getContent(sid, docId);

InputStream is = handler.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/tmp/myFile.raw"));

// This will copy the file from the two streams
IOUtils.copy(is, os);

// This will close two streams catching exception
IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
```

Comment: where can i get the sid and docid ?